# ¿Cómo detectar si hay nuevas actualizaciones del propio programa desarrollado en Python?

Tags: python

Pretendo alojar mi programa Python ya compilado en la sección *release* de GitHub o en su defecto en algún sitio como Google Drive o similar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que el usuario ejecute el programa este chequee si hay nuevos lanzamientos? Y de ser así, pueda abrir el *link* de descarga en el navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en la que yo lo hago es crear una variable al interno del programa con la versión del mismo de manera que luego puedo comparar la versión del programa ejecutado con la versión online. El único inconveniente es recordar actualizar la variable con la nueva versión al interno del programa antes de hacer un nuevo release.

GitHub provee un modo de acceder a la última versión de un programa sin necesidad de conocer su número utilizando la palabra `latest` en vez de especificar una versión en el URL. De modo que puedes usar la librería `requests` y hacer un `get()` en este link para obtener el link de redireccionamiento que contiene el número de la última versión, ejemplo:

```
requests.get('https://github.com/ariel-mn/js-vido/releases/latest')
print(r.url)
```

Devuelve:

```
https://github.com/ariel-mn/js-vido/releases/tag/v1.0.0
```

Luego es cuestión de obtener el número de la última versión disponible haciendo un `split` al URL y compararlo con la versión del programa que está siendo ejecutado, en caso de que las versiones sean diferentes mostrarás el mensaje. A continuación un ejemplo completo:

```
import requests

# Version del programa ejecutado
version="v1.0.0"

# Enlace al ultimo release
link = 'https://github.com/ariel-mn/js-vido/releases/latest'

# Obtiene el enlace del redireccionamiento que contiene la version
r=requests.get(link)

# Obtiene la ultima version disponible
version_online = r.url.split('/')[-1]

# Compara ambas versiones
if version != version_online:
    print(f'Hay una nueva version del programa, puede descargarla aquí: {link}')
```

Otra forma de obtener la última versión de un `release` sin necesidad de utilizar `split` (en lo personal, mi preferida) es por medio de la API de GitHub que responde en formato Json. Esta es la manera de hacerlo:

```
response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/ariel-mn/js-vido/releases/latest")
version_online = response.json()["tag_name"]
```

Si quieres abrir el link en un navegador sin consultar al usuario, puedes utilizar lo siguiente que utiliza el navegador configurado como preferido en el sistema:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(link)
```

> La librería requests hay que instalarla con `pip install requests` en vez `webbrowser` ya viene integrada en Python así que no es necesario instalarla.

Comment: Solo me queda una duda.
por qué si hago help(requests.get.url) para conocer mejor la función, python señala que no existe el atributo "url", sinembargo en el código que me indicas, funciona bien.

Comment: Porque en mi código no hago `get.url`,  hago `r.url` donde `r` es un objeto generado por `requests`

Comment: Si quieres conocer mejor una librería lo recomendable es dirigirse a la documentación, te dejo el enlace a la [documentación oficial](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta añadiendo un método diferente más practico